Are soft reference object and strong reference refer each other will cause interlocking?
Strong Reference to object and that object soft reference back to this.
My program has a list of product sales record, and product itself refer the order object.
program has a function summaries order detail, it use order's product sales to calculate something.
Most Important I question is that will cause YGC not clearing them when I set list of product sales record to null?

Are you using soft references or weak references? Based on some past experience using these, soft references with no hard references to them will not be gc'd until the heap would run out of memory (before throwing an outOfMemoryError) trying to satisfy new allocations. Weak references will be gc'd when the hard reference(s) to them have been garbage collected.

Using setter-based dependency injection instead of constructor-based is another way of fixing circular dependency/circular reference if you are using spring framework.
For hibernate entity mappings, fetch type 'lazy' might help instead of fetch 'eager', so data will load only on demand.
In most cases, circular references are unavoidable but try to avoid mapping entities that leads to circular references as much as possible unless it is absolutely necessary
